# replicating contents from a SPARQL endpoint locally with Jena

Tags: jena, apache-jena

I'd like to replicate the contents of a SPARQL endpoint locally and then query those data locally

Because it's somewhat large dataset I don't think a memory based model would fit

But I can't find any example of a model with some initial content AND a storage setting different from a in memory storage.

Is this possible ? How do I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to have a local SPARQL endpoint and load a dataset into it you can install a Fuseki SPARQL server (which can create a persistent TDB RDF store for you):

- [Running a Fuseki Server](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/#running-a-fuseki-server)

If you want to create a persistent RDF store using Java, use the [TDBFactory.createDataset(path) method](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/tdb/org/apache/jena/tdb/TDBFactory.html#createDataset-java.lang.String-). The dataset can be batch-loaded into the store using the [tdbloader](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/commands.html#tdbloader) tool.

P.S. there's also a Semantic Web QA site - here's an answer to a question similar to yours:

- [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/18178/creating-a-tdb-backed-model](https://web.archive.org/web/20150722174927/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/18178/creating-a-tdb-backed-model)